# How to use facebook restserver.php

Tags: facebook

Well, I need to use rest api (api.facebook.com/restserver.php) of facebook but I never used this authentication method, I just used oauth with access_token.

Someone could help me?

I do not know how to get the parameters session_key and sig.

I need something like this:

http://api.facebook.com/restserver.php?api_key=myapikey&format=XML&method=facebook.fql.query&query=SELECT id,name,first_name,last_name FROM user WHERE uid=my_uid&session_key=?????&sig=??????&v=1.0

I need to use restserver.php with session_key and sig, but I dont know how get it.
Some idea

Thanks
Alexandre

Comment: Why do you need to use this deprecated endpoint?

Comment: Because my boss wants, he did not tell me why

Comment: does your boss know they are going to kill this endpoint soon?

Answer (score 1):

The old rest url you are trying to use is deprecated.  If you are trying to run a FQL query, you can now use the [FQL with the graph API](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/fql/).  You would just use your access_token and do an HTTP GET to: https://developers.facebook.com/fql?q=SELECT...&access_token=...

Comment: But it still works (facebook application for android uses it). As I said before I have to use this api and wondered if anyone knows how to use.